# Difference between UIImage and UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

What is the difference between `UIImage` and `UIImageView`? Can someone explain it with an example?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Example:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x.png"];
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
backgroundImageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

[`UIImage` Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A `UIImage` object is a high-level way to display image data. You can
>   create images from files, from Quartz image objects, or from raw image
>   data you receive. The UIImage class also offers several options for
>   drawing images to the current graphics context using different blend
>   modes and opacity values.
>
> Image objects are immutable, so you cannot change their properties
>   after creation. This means that you generally specify an image’s
>   properties at initialization time or rely on the image’s metadata to
>   provide the property value. In some cases, however, the UIImage class
>   provides convenience methods for obtaining a copy of the image that
>   uses custom values for a property.
>
> Because image objects are immutable, they also do not provide direct
>   access to their underlying image data. However, you can get an NSData
>   object containing either a PNG or JPEG representation of the image
>   data using the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`
>   functions.
>
> The system uses image objects to represent still pictures taken with
>   the camera on supported devices. To take a picture, use the
>   UIImagePickerController class. To save a picture to the Saved Photos
>   album, use the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function.

[`UIImageView` Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An `UIImageView`  provides a view-based container for displaying
>   either a single image or for animating a series of images. For
>   animating the images, the `UIImageView` class provides controls to set
>   the duration and frequency of the animation. You can also start and
>   stop the animation freely.
>
> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by
>   default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of
>   `UIImageView`, you must explicitly change the value of the
>   `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES` after initializing the object.
>
> When a `UIImageView` object displays one of its images, the actual
>   behavior is based on the properties of the image and the view. If
>   either of the image’s `leftCapWidth` or `topCapHeight` properties are
>   non-zero, then the image is stretched according to the values in those
>   properties. Otherwise, the image is scaled, sized to fit, or
>   positioned in the image view according to the contentMode property of
>   the view. It is recommended (but not required) that you use images
>   that are all the same size. If the images are different sizes, each
>   will be adjusted to fit separately based on that mode.
>
> All images associated with a `UIImageView` object should use the same
>   scale. If your application uses images with different scales, they may
>   render incorrectly.

Answer (score 17):

`UIImage` contains the data for an image.
`UIImageView` is a custom view meant to display the `UIImage`.

Answer (score 13):

In short: 
You create an instance of `UIImage` object to hold image's data, like this:

```
 NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/picture.jpg"]; //assuming your image is in your app's bundle
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath];
```

You then create an instance of `UIImageView` either through IB or code to display your image on the screen, like this:

```
[imageView1 setImage:img];  //assume you already create an instance of UIImageView named imageView1
```

Answer (score 8):

`UIImage` is a data object that holds image bytes.

`UIImageView` is a control that display `UIImage` data.

Answer (score 7):

`UIImage` objects store data from an image (i.e. data from a png file)

`UIImageView` objects are used to display a `UIImage`

Answer (score 2):

`UIimage` is an Object which stores data (Jpg, png...)
and `UIImageView` class which contains `UIImage` as a property.
`UIImageView` can have multiple `UIImages`, and `UIImage` is immutable.
That bothered me a long time ago, when you create an image you do:

```
 var image: UIImageView!
```

But when you execute that "image" you do

```
image.image = UIImage.init(named: "image")
```

Its really easy, you use `UIimageView`, to create an image with `UIImage`.
`UIImage` displays the image, and `UIImageView` is a container for that `UIImage`.

Answer (score 0):

UIImage holds the data as like (pictures) and displays it on UIImageView.

UIImageView is a type of container to display images.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
```

create an instance for UIImageView as "myImage".This is helps for dispaly data.UIImage helps for hold the data of 1.png from the assets file in the xcode.